# Нужен совет для оформления контрастного анализа (ПЕРЕВОДЧИКИ, Ваша помощь нужна!)

Tags: общие-вопросы

Друзья, я учусь на учителя и нормы перевода нам очень коротко были объяснены, поэтому я сейчас в небольшом тупике. 
Как нам объясняли, при переводе важно донести смысл оригинала. 
А что делать, если тексты сильно отличаются друг от друга?

Пример:

Предложение в оригинале: *Но прежде чем он мог поблагодарить его за визит, он прижал шляпу к сердцу,* ............

Русский перевод: *Нo радость была недолгой: он прижал шляпу к сердцу, ......................*

Другой пример:

В итальянском предложение звучит таким образом:

*Перепрыгнул на соседнюю ветку, чуть повыше, однако там его достать было легче, так как там была приставлена лестница еще до того, как приехали пожарные.*

Русский перевод:

*Перепрыгнул на соседнюю ветку, чуть повыше, однако там его достать было легче, поскольку именно к ней пожарными была приставлена лестница.*

Меня такое отличие не сильно беспокоило бы, если бы не мое задание: определить модус и тип предложения. Когда в одном языке используется сослагательное наклонение и тип предложения например придаточное времени, то в другом языке стоит изъявительное в простом предложении. Мне необходимы какие-то идеи, как это можно объяснить. Или всё сваливать на свободную руку переводчика?

Answer (score 5):

В обоих примерах, особенно в первом, имеет место недопустимая вольность. Разумеется, и буквальный перевод, несмотря на отсутствие в тексте идиом и т.п. здесь не использовать как окончательный вариант, поскольку фраза получается нерусской (неестественный порядок слов, нетипичные обороты, выражающие последовательность действий и т.п). При переводе важно не просто донести смысл оригинала (это верная рекомендация), а сделать это по возможности точно: **уяснив точный смысл, сформулировать его средствами второго языка** - так, как сказал бы в той же ситуации его носитель. При этом вполне может оказаться, что в переводе  другой порядок слов (более характерный для второго языка), использованы другие части речи и другое наклонение. Например, английская фраза wish you were here (букв. "хочу, чтобы ты был здесь"; подразумевается отсутствие того, о ком говорят) по смыслу переводится как "жаль, что тебя нет рядом/здесь" - для русского языка более типична другая форма выражения сожаления.

Поэтому обычно начинают с точного выяснения смысла, который заложен в исходном тексте, и оценки возможности буквального перевода (в простейших случаях это возможно и может оказаться лучшим вариантом) с точки зрения естественности такого выражения и применимости его в той же ситуации.

Answer (score 3):

В практике и теории перевода есть понятие: переводческие трансформации. Это именно те трансформации, которые Вы приводите в качестве примера. Действительно, в художественном переводе лучше отойти от подстрочника и передать ту же мысль средствами языка-перевода.  То же касается и других видов перевода ( за исключением тех текстов, где важен дословный перевод).Если Вы изучаете английский, могу посоветовать пособие по переводу. Теория и практика перевода.  Т. Кабакчи. В пособии представлены базовые знания. Думаю, для начала это Вам поможет.

Comment: передать **ту же** мысль!!! А в приведенных переводах или отсебятина, или вообще искажение смысла. Может не надо защищать бездаря-переводягу: Traduttore — traditore

Comment: Lazy Badger, прежде чем делать поспешные выводы, надо, как отметил Марк, знать контекст, знать, насколько важна та или иная информация в тексте,а потом уже судить.

Answer (score 3):

В обоих случаях переводчик пытался избежать тавтологии (*он-он, там-там*). И в том, и в другом случае представленный перевод может быть как очень удачным, так и ужасным, без контекста не понять. В первом случае исчезло намерение поблагодарить, во втором - что лестница приставлена была не пожарными. Если эти обстоятельства важны для понимания текста, то перевод плох, если не имеют значения - вполне приемлем.